# how to change backgroundcolor of divs when they are clicked in angular2

Tags: angular

Here, divs are created in a loop. I want first div to have a default blue color and rest black backgroundcolor. when other div are clicked that div become blue and other black.
How to do that ?

```
app.component.ts
------------------------
tabsData = ['a', 'br', 'Sp', 'hh','ee'];

    app.component.html
    ---------------------
    <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm tabsMenu" id="navBar">
            <div class="">
                <div  class="navMenu  menu-list " (click)="changeClass($event)"  *ngFor="let tab of tabsData;let i = index; let frst=first" [ngClass]="{'active': isSelected, 'active': frst}" >
                    {{tab}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Instead of a boolean isSelected field, which can't possibly tell you *what* is selected, you need a selectedTab field, containing the selected tab. Then, in your ngClass, you can just use `active: tab === selectedTab`

Comment: How about you trying it? It's not that hard. Almost everything is in m comment already.

Comment: <div  class="navMenu  menu-list " (click)="changeClass($event)"  *ngFor="let tab of tabsData;let i = index; let frst=first" [ngClass]="{'active': tab === selectedTab, 'active': frst}" >
                {{tab}}

Comment: Its not working

Comment: So, what does your changeClass() method do? You realize it needs to set the selectedTab to the current tab, right? Otherwise, what's the point? So it should be selectTab(tab), and it should initialize the selected tab to the tab passed as argument. It seems you trying to do what I suggest, but without trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is often best to store this state in the view model (component) when possible. You might try something like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-component',
    template: `
        <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm tabsMenu" id="navBar">
            <div class="">
                <div class="navMenu menu-list"
                        *ngFor="let tab of tabsData"
                        (click)="selected = tab"
                        [class.active]="tab === selected">
                    {{tab}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public tabsData: Tab[] = [];
    public selected: Tab;

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.selected = tabsData[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: here,tabsData = ['a', 'br', 'Sp', 'hh','ee']. But, you have passed @Input() public tabsData: Tab[] = [];